# How to send a tweet with jTwitter on Android?

Tags: android, service, oauth, signpost, jtwitter

Has anyone ever successfully sent a tweet via jTwitter on Android?

I am stuck with the Authentification. I can successfully redirect the user to twitter, authorize my app and redirect to my app with `new OAuthSignpostClient(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, CALLBACK_URL)`. Then I store the `oauth_token` and `oauth_verifier` which are given with the Callback URL and try to use the OAuthSignpostClient again to update a state:

```
OAuthSignpostClient client = new OAuthSignpostClient(TwitterOAuthActivity.CONSUMER_KEY, TwitterOAuthActivity.CONSUMER_SECRET, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);

// Ready to go!
Twitter twitter = new Twitter(null, client);
CharSequence date = DateFormat.format("dd.MM.yyyy @ hh:mm:ss", new Date());
twitter.updateStatus("Yay. It works! " + date);
```

Which ends in a `TwitterException` without a caused by:

```
05-11 12:24:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(25897): winterwell.jtwitter.TwitterException$E401: Could not authenticate with OAuth.
05-11 12:24:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(25897): http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json (anonymous)
05-11 12:24:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(25897):    at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.processError(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:425) 
05-11 12:24:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(25897):    at winterwell.jtwitter.OAuthSignpostClient.post2_connect(OAuthSignpostClient.java:345)
```

Does anyone has an idea where my Problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The verifier from the callback url is a temporary key. It let's you unlock the OAuthSignpostClient object that you have. You can't use it to construct a new OAuthSignpostClient.

You need to call:

```
client.setAuthorizationCode(verifier);
// The client can now be used!
// To use it again, without the oauth dance, store _these_ tokens:
String[] tokens = client.getAccessToken();
```

You may also want to check out the new AndroidTwitterLogin class which makes things easy:

```
AndroidTwitterLogin atl = new AndroidTwitterLogin(myApp, 
                MY_TWITTER_KEY,MY_TWITTER_SECRET,MY_TWITTER_CALLBACK) {                 

    protected void onSuccess(Twitter jtwitter, String[] tokens) {
        jtwitter.setStatus("I can now post to Twitter!");
        // Recommended: store tokens in your app for future use
        // with the constructor OAuthSignpostClient(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String accessToken, String accessTokenSecret)
    }
};
atl.run();
```